# If ions are floating around in a solution, how do we know they combine to form a compound in a solution?

Tags: solutions

I apologize if my question sounds confusing I am not sure how to properly convey it here's an example:

For the reaction between lead nitrate and ammonium phosphate you get the reaction:

$$\ce{3Pb(NO3)2 (aq) + 2(NH4)3PO4(aq) -> Pb3(PO4)2(s) + 6NH4NO3(aq)}$$

but the ionic equation is 
$$\ce{3Pb2+(aq) + 6NO3-(aq) +6NH4+(aq) + 2PO4^3-(aq) -> Pb3(PO3)2(s) + 6NH4+(aq) + 6NO3-(aq)}$$

so how do we know the compound $\ce{6NH4NO3}$ is formed if its just $\ce{6NH4+}$ and $\ce{6NO3-}$? Do the ions combine and then immidiately disassociate again? I'm very highly confused I would appreciate an explanation, and i apologize if this makes no sense.

Comment: In a beginning chemistry course, we just say all ammonium salts are soluble. So the solution in your example has ammonium and nitrate ions just bouncing around. Filtering out the lead phosphate and evaporating the water would give solid ammonium nitrate, with some lead phosphate impurity.

Comment: ahhhhh I see so what it's saying is that ammonium nitrate can be formed not that it is actually being formed?

Comment: Exactly! We also say, in the beginning chemistry course, that all nitrates are soluble, so ammonium nitrate is soluble on both counts. As the water evaporates, you get to the solubility limit of ammonium nitrate. Then, with further evaporation, solid ammonium nitrate is formed, unless the solution is becomes supersaturated. Even then, solid ammonium nitrate will form once the supersaturated solution gets nucleated by whatever, i.e., particles, scratches on the inside of the vessel, beard droppings, etc.

Comment: oh I see, thank you i was having trouble with this a lot, one other quick question that's kind of related to this that i was having some trouble with is that when we make a net ionic equation of the equation above, I don't understand how it's possible that some ions don't react at all or are unchanged?

Comment: Spectator ions are necessary for charge and mass balance, but they simply do not react under the circumstances. Really, it is as simple as that: there is no free energy favorable reaction for them to do.

Comment: In the second equation $\ce{6NH4+(s)}$ should be $\ce{6NH4+(aq)}$

Comment: Oh thank you, and oh I did not notice that I'll fix that right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User EdV comments above get to the heart of the matter. To summarize:

Your first equation is typically how a chemist would write the reaction.

$$\ce{3Pb(NO3)2 (aq) + 2(NH4)3PO4(aq) -> Pb3(PO4)2(s) + 6NH4NO3(aq)}$$

The equation is a "shorthand" explanation. What a chemist reads is:

- On the left hand side is that that two solutions are mixed together.

  - Since $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ has an "(aq)" modifier it will be in solution, but since it is an ionic compound it will not be in solution as a molecule, but rather as the $\ce{Pb^{2+}}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ ions.
  - Since $\ce{(NH4)3PO4}$ has an "(aq)" modifier it will be in solution, but since it is an ionic compound it will not be in solution as a molecule, but rather as the $\ce{NH4+}$ and $\ce{PO4^{3-}}$ ions.
  - Since the RHS shows a reaction the two salts can't be in one solution simultaneously. Therefore the salts must have been dissolved in separate solutions and the solutions were mixed.
- On the right hand side $\ce{Pb3(PO4)2}$ precipitates and $\ce{6NH4NO3}$ remains in solution.

  - Also since $\ce{Pb3(PO4)2}$ has a tiny but finite solubility, a very small amount of $\ce{Pb3(PO4)2}$ will remain in solution.
  - Since $\ce{NH4NO3}$ has an "(aq)" modifier it will be in solution, but since it is an ionic compound it will not be in solution as a molecule, but rather as the $\ce{NH4+}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ ions.

The "ionic equation" is harder to understand because of its verbosity. Did the $\ce{NO3-}$ ions come into the solution with the $\ce{Pb^{2+}}$ ions or the $\ce{NH4+}$ ions? Being chemists we can puzzle it out, but the equation is less succinct. 
$$\ce{3Pb2+(aq) + 6NO3-(aq) +6NH4+(aq) + 2PO4^3-(aq) -> Pb3(PO3)2(s) + 6NH4+(aq) + 6NO3-(aq)}$$

Comment: All this has already be already mentioned in EdV answers.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks, but no problem from my point of view: anyone is welcome (and encouraged) to post a good (or great) answer that benefits both the OP and the site.